# Form with radio buttons and one input field. Calculate the value depending on radio button selcted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I would like to convert the temperature given in Celsius to Fahrenheit degrees or the other way round. I would like the unit to be chosen via radio button form and the converted units calculated with JS function. However, I am doing something wrong, and I am not sure what exactly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<body>
<p>Convert temperatures to and from celsius, fahrenheit.</p>
<p id="myForm>
    <form name="units" onsubmit="return convertTemp();" method="post">
        <input type="number" id="temp"><br>
        Temperature in:
        <fieldset>
            <input type="radio" name="Temperature" id="c" value="c" checked><label for="c">Celsius degrees</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Temperature" id="f" value="f"><label for="f">Fahrenheit degrees</label>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Oblicz">
    <form>
</p>
<p id="wynik"></p>
```

And here is my JavaScript function:

```
function convertTemp() {
        alert("Włączyła się");
        var x = document.Jednostki.Temperature.value;
        if (x == "c"){
            alert("Celsjusz");
        }
        else if (x == "f"){
            alert("Fahrenheit");
        }
        returns false;
    }
```

Comment: close your form id as well. `id="myForm">`

Comment: I can't see `Jednostki` in your HTML code which you have stated in your JS code on line 3;

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I have updated it to more appropriate eventlistener usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("units").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Włączyła się");
    var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("temp").value, 10);
    if (document.getElementById("c").checked) {
      console.log("Celsjusz");
      document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML = num + "C," + (Math.round(num * 9 / 5) + 32) + "F";
    } else if (document.getElementById("f").checked) {
      console.log("Fahrenheit");
      document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML = num + "F," + (Math.round((num - 32) * 5 / 9)) + "C";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<p>Convert temperatures to and from celsius, fahrenheit.</p>
<p>
  <form id="units">
    <input type="number" id="temp"><br> Temperature in:
    <fieldset>
      <input type="radio" name="Temperature" id="c" value="c" checked><label for="c">Celsius degrees</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Temperature" id="f" value="f"><label for="f">Fahrenheit degrees</label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Oblicz">
    <form>
</p>
<p id="wynik"></p>
```

Using querySelector:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("units").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Włączyła się");
    const num = parseInt(document.getElementById("temp").value, 10);
    const type = document.querySelector("[name=Temperature]:checked").value;
    if (type==="c") {
      console.log("Celsjusz");
      document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML = num + "C," + (Math.round(num * 9 / 5) + 32) + "F";
    } else {
      console.log("Fahrenheit");
      document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML = num + "F," + (Math.round((num - 32) * 5 / 9)) + "C";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<p>Convert temperatures to and from celsius, fahrenheit.</p>
<p>
  <form id="units">
    <input type="number" id="temp"><br> Temperature in:
    <fieldset>
      <input type="radio" name="Temperature" id="c" value="c" checked><label for="c">Celsius degrees</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Temperature" id="f" value="f"><label for="f">Fahrenheit degrees</label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Oblicz">
    <form>
</p>
<p id="wynik"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

First issue I see: `returns false;` should be `return false;` (no s).

You should also retrieve the values using document.getElementById():

```
function convertTemp() {
    alert("Włączyła się");

    var celsius = document.getElementById('c');
    var fahr = document.getElementById('f');
    if (c.checked){
        alert("Celsjusz");
    }
    else{
        alert("Fahrenheit");
    }
    return false;
}

document.getElementById("units").onsubmit = convertTemp;
```

Answer (score -1):

using jquery you can do  it raplce this line

```
 var x = document.Jednostki.Temperature.value;
```

to

```
var x = $('input[name="Temperature"]:checked').val()
```

you can see it [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/3n1pr505/) 
to get  jquery [click here](http://jquery.com)